# Fix missing start script in angular2 package.json

Tags: angular

I have configured angular 2 in Ubuntu and when i run npn start in the command i get "missing script: start" error.

I found the issue that npm start script is missing in package.json.

But even after including the start script in my package.json, i get errors.

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
   "start": "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
```

**On updating the above start script line, i get error like:**

Failed to parse package.json data.
 npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

My project folder doesnt seem to have any .js file .

Here is a view of my project folder contents:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start configuration in package.json is incorrect, you need to change it to next one if you use cli:

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"
```

or if you want to use lite server to:

```
"start": "lite-server"
```

Comment: tried both, for ng i replaced my ubuntu servers IP addr for both i m getting ng not found and lite-server not found respectively

Comment: You need to install lite server to your project, instructions are here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server